# Checking if $M := \{(x,y,z,w)^T \in \mathbb{R}^4 \vert 1 < x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 \leq 4 \}$ is closed/bounded/compact

Tags: calculus, general-topology, compactness

We have a set $M := \{(x,y,z,w)^T \in \mathbb{R}^4 \vert 1 < x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 \leq 4 \}$

I want to check (formally) if the set is closed, bounded and compact.

In my script it says,

- $M$ is closed if $M^C$ is open.
- $M$ is bounded if $M \subset U_K(0)$ for $K > 0$
- $M$ is compact if $M$ is closed and bounded.

To answer whether M is closed or not, I would have said that
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 +w^2$  is continous on $[1,4]$ and therefore closed.

Since it's closed and bounded by $1$ and $4$ it's also compact.

But that's not a formal proof and when I looked online this topic always gets covered on multiple sites only.

Can someone show me where or how one can show if this set is closed/bounded/compact formally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To answer whether M is closed or not, I would have said that
> $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 +w^2$  is continous on $[1,4]$ and therefore closed.

That is wrong. First of all it should've been $(1,4]$, because your left inequality in $M$ is strict. But what is more important, $(1,4]$ is not a domain for this function, so its not "continuous on". Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$. What is true is that $M=f^{-1}((1,4])$ instead. Which doesn't tell us much, since $(1,4]$ is neither open nor closed.

$M$ is not closed. Consider the sequence $(x_n,y_n,z_n,w_n)=(1+1/n,0,0,0)$ which is fully contained in $M$ but its limit $(1,0,0,0)$ is not. Since it is not closed then it cannot be compact as well.

$M$ is not open. Because $M^c$ is not closed. By similar argument, the sequenc e $(x_n,y_n,z_n,w_n)=(2+1/n,0,0,0)$ is fully contained in $M^c$ but its limit $(2,0,0,0)$ is not.

$M$ is bounded. Because $M$ is fully contained in the open ball centered at $(0,0,0,0)$ of any radius greater than $4$, say $5$.